# Scala map sorting

Tags: sorting, scala, dictionary

How do I sort a map of this kind:

```
"01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34)
```

by the beginning values?

Comment: Do you need need the result to be another map, or are you just interested in forgetting the keys once they've been used for the sorting?

Comment: I need result in another map.

Comment: i think that maps are unsorted by definition, aren't they?

Comment: Sorry I do not know the definition of map, and i needed it in sorted way ;)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

One way is to use scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap, which is always sorted by keys:

```
val t = TreeMap("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))

//If  you have already a map...
val m = Map("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
//... use this
val t = TreeMap(m.toSeq:_*)
```

You can convert it to a Seq or List and sort it, too:

```
//by specifying an element for sorting
m.toSeq.sortBy(_._1) //sort by comparing keys
m.toSeq.sortBy(_._2) //sort by comparing values

//by providing a sort function
m.toSeq.sortWith(_._1 < _._1) //sort by comparing keys
```

There are plenty of possibilities, each more or less convenient in a certain context.

Comment: You can also append an arbitrarily sorted sequence to a `LinkedHashMap`, which will retain the insertion order for traversal.

Comment: heh heh, just updated my answer to use `.toseq:_*`, didn't spot that you'd already done it!  Promise I'm not stealing :)

Comment: Reading Kevin's answer, using SortedMap seems to be the better style, as it shows clearly what behavior you need, not which implementation.

Comment: Is TreeMap sorted by contract or by implementation?

Comment: @Raphael By contract -- it extends SortedMap

Comment: what does expression :_* mean in TreeMap(m.toSeq:_*)? I am not able to get that

Comment: If anyone else is wondering like me. The expression is to covert seq in to varargs. see more explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala

Comment: Is there any easy way to return the first X elements of the list once it's ordered?

Comment: How about `list.take(42)`?

Answer (score 16):

As stated, the default `Map` type is unsorted, but there's always `SortedMap`

```
import collection.immutable.SortedMap
SortedMap("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
```

Although I'm guessing you can't use that, because I recognise this homework and suspect that YOUR map is the result of a groupBy operation.  So you have to create an empty SortedMap and add the values:

```
val unsorted = Map("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
val sorted = SortedMap.empty[String, List[Int]] ++ unsorted
//or
val sorted = SortedMap(unsorted.toSeq:_*)
```

Or if you're not wedded to the `Map` interface, you can just convert it to a sequence of tuples.  Note that this approach will only work if both the keys and values have a defined ordering. Lists don't have a default ordering defined, so this won't work with your example code - I therefore made up some other numbers instead.

```
val unsorted = Map("01" -> 56, "11" -> 34)
val sorted = unsorted.toSeq.sorted
```

This might be useful if you can first convert your lists to some other type (such as a String), which is best done using `mapValues`

**update:**  See Landei's answer, which shows how you can provide a custom sort function that'll make this approach work.