# How to reverse map and loop through keys and values in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, collections, hdfs

I am writing a Scala Spark script where I am storing (Hive partitions) HDFS paths as keys and their underlying file count as values. I want to write a for loop to check if the filepath exists (using key) and count is greater than 0. I have to reverse the whole map because I want to start checking for latest partition.

I couldn't find any method to reverse the map and loop through it. 
Here's my code:

```
val paths = collection.mutable.Map[String, Float]()
status.foreach( x => paths += (x.getPath.toString -> fs.getContentSummary(new Path(x.getPath.toString).getFileCount() )
```

This is what I am planning to do :

```
//Reverse the map to make last element as first element
var result = ""
for ((k,v) <- paths) {
if(!fs.exists(new Path(k)) && v < 1)
  continue
else
  result = k
  break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Up Vote" if answer works for you.

You need to use ListMap and then you sort map based on key ( basically you can reverse the map and perform further operations ).

import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

val paths_sortBy_key_asc = ListMap(paths.toSeq.sortBy(_._1) < _.*1:**)

```
or
```

val paths_sortBy_key_dsc = ListMap(paths.toSeq.sortBy(_._1) > _.*1:**)

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options.

1. Use TreeMap to construct data structure. Its is sorted by keys.
2. Convert it to a seq or list and sort it.

All these options are outlined here  with an example.

refer to [sort map link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793490/scala-map-sorting)